# Implementation of mdi_init of the gmp library in C

Tags: c, gmp

I am trying to implement my own version of the GMP mpz_t data type in C.
For that , I am facing a problem in defining the structure for mpz_t.

This is because I am defining my mpz_t like this

```
typedef struct integer
{
int array[100];
int no_digits;
}mdi;
```

Clearly, I am storing my large values as an array of integer data types and no_digits is the number of digits in the structure.
But now, for the init function , I have to meet the following prototype

```
void mdi_init(mdi x); // Initialises the data-type.
```

Here the return type is void and the input parameter is of type mdi.
I am confused as to how to meet this requirement with my definition of mdi.

Help needed.

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  Are you trying to re-implement your own version of GMP?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to implement my own version of GMP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am confused as to how to meet this requirement with my definition of mdi.

You can't.

`struct`s are passed by value, so a function taking an `mdi` as an argument cannot change the passed argument.

GMP defines `mpz_t` as an array (of length 1) of `__mpz_struct`s,

```
typedef __mpz_struct mpz_t[1];
```

and `__mpz_struct` is analogous to your `mdi` struct. So `mpz_init()` receives a pointer to an `__mpz_struct`. You would need to do the same, you can make `mdi_init()` explicitly take a pointer to an `mdi` as argument, or, like GMP, make `mdi` an array (of length 1) of `mdi_struct`s.